# Client Application Services and VSPackage

Tags: .net, vspackage

I'm currently developing a VSPackage, and it will have some log-in functionality external to the system, so I thought I would use Client Application Services.

I have followed online tutorials word for word and cannot seem to get a VSPackage to return true for the following:

```
Membership.ValidateUser("username", "password")
```

I have created a simple skeleton winforms application that succesfully returns true on this call, showing that membership is working here.

However, the call simply returns false on the VSPackage no-matter what username/password I choose. There are no exceptions thrown from what I can see.

Is there a limitation somewhere due to VSPackages? I have LINQ-to-SQL running inside the package also and the DB calls work fine, so I am baffled as to why it isn't working as expected.

Both the VSPackage and Winforms app share the same app.config files.

Any Ideas?

Cheers,
MiG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I switched to using Windows Authentication instead of Forms. It seems app.config is ignored entirely by VSPackages and couldn't find much on the internet as to why this is.